# Truncate text in an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

Here is the JSFiddle I'm trying to do: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wndjf07e/2/)

It is responsive, and in a large width, it is exactly what I want, like this:

[image]

But in small sizes, It overlaps the another text and/or breaks the lines, like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

And this is my css to the texts:

```
.giro-nome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
}

.giro-percentual {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 25%;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

I wanted just to stop the text in a single line, something like this(expected, not real):

[image]

Is it possible? Probably not with absolute, like I'm doing, but I have no idea another way to do it.

Thank you advanced.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow); is what you're looking for.

> **[8.2. Overflow Ellipsis: the ‘text-overflow’ property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow)**
>
> This property specifies rendering when inline content overflows its
>   block container element ("the block") in its inline progression
>   direction that has ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’. Text can overflow
>   for example when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g. due to
>   ‘white-space:nowrap’ or a single word is too long to fit). Values have
>   the following meanings:
>
> **ellipsis** Render an ellipsis character (U+2026) to represent clipped inline content. Implementations may substitute a more
>   language/script-appropriate ellipsis character, or three dots "..." if
>   the ellipsis character is unavailable.

However you should specify the width of the absolutely positioned element at first. Either by `left`/`right` properties, or by other approaches such as `width: 90%` or `width: calc(100% - 80px)`:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wndjf07e/9/)**

```css
.giro-nome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0; right: 80px;  /* Equal to > width: calc(100% - 80px) */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the below css properties this will truncate your overflow text and append the three dots.

```
.giro-nome {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to work but not working in the fiddle actually because `.giro-nome` doesn't have any width declared.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but the @Hashem Qolami answer is more complete and worked like a charm ^^